# "What is your travel status?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a job offer, I encountered a question "What is your travel status". What does "travel status" mean in this context?

The company offering is from a different country than the receiver of the offer. The receiver would be working remotely.

Comment: "A business proposal" does not give adequate context for an answer.  Without context, a "meaning-in-context" question will soon be closed.

Comment: @jwpat7 I am not sure I understand your position. What would be adequate context?

Comment: @ipavlic: explain more about the "business proposal."  Who wrote it?  For what purpose?  And what about the question at hand?  In what section of the document was it found?

Comment: @J.R. I've added some more information, but I think both you and Mehper understood the question correctly.

Comment: Do not guess. These terms have specific definitions which are inviolable and not open to interpretations. Where no reference is available, **ask**: the source of the job offer (?the prospective employer).

Answer (score 2):

I guess they're asking whether you are available to travel for business trips. In some job interviews, they may ask you how much of the time you would be available for business trips, i.e. 25%, 50%, 100% etc.

Comment: It might also be asking whether or not you would be available for international travel (passports in place, etc.).

Comment: @J.R Please create an answer with your information so that I can upvote it.